# Indy to use Windows CertStore?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there any way that Indy can use a cert from the windows store? I currently use `TidServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` but dont see an option there. Any tricks to achieve this?

Comment: OpenSSL does not support the Windows Certificate Store, only its own built-in store.  There are ways to export Windows certificates and import them into OpenSSL, but that is outside the scope of Indy.

Answer (score 1):

This project is a Indy Handler to Windows Secure Channel.
https://github.com/tothpaul/Delphi/tree/master/Indy.SChannel

The handler has a function named "LoadCertificatStore" wich reads PFX data stored in a CRYPT_DATA_BLOB structure.

You can copy your certificate (and its chain) from the Windows system store to a temporal memory store, export to a memory PFX and read it from the handler.